# Creating Docker container for a micro-service based on node.js & grpc

Tags: node.js, docker, grpc

I am trying to build a chat-service by using node.js and grpc, where two services running on different port can communicate to each other. I have created a single ".js" file where I wrote the code for server part as well as client part and I run that file by passing env variables. To run two different services from one single file I use this command SERVER_PORT=2000 CLIENT_PORT=5000 node filename(in one terminal) and
SERVER_PORT=5000 CLIENT_PORT=2000 node filename(in another) after this two services were able to chat.

In my local machine it was working but after building docker image, two docker containers and docker-compose.yml I am getting "Circular Dependency" error.
I recently started working on these things and I am stuck.

Please share your views on this. Thank you in advance.

my .js file

```
var PROTO_PATH = "./allenchat.proto";
//var vv = require('./allenchat.proto');
var dotEnv = require("dotenv").config();

var grpc = require("grpc");
var protoLoader = require("@grpc/proto-loader");
var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, {
  keepCase: true,
  longs: String,
  enums: String,
  defaults: true,
  oneofs: true,
});
var protoDescriptor = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);

var grpcChat = protoDescriptor.io.mark.grpc.grpcChat;
var clients = new Map();
const Server_Add = process.env.ADD_PORT;
const Client_Add = process.env.FRND_PORT;

function chat(call) {
  call.on("data", function (ChatMessage) {
    user = call.metadata.get("username");
    msg = ChatMessage.message;
    console.log(`${user} ==> ${msg}`);
    for (let [msgUser, userCall] of clients) {
      if (msgUser != user) {
        userCall.write({
          from: user,
          message: msg,
        });
      }
    }
    if (clients.get(user) === undefined) {
      clients.set(user, call);
    }
  });
  call.on("end", function () {
    call.write({
      fromName: "Chat server",
      message: "Nice to see ya! Come back again...",
    });
    call.end();
  });
}

var host = "0.0.0.0";
var server = new grpc.Server();
server.addService(grpcChat.ChatService.service, {
  chat: chat,
});
server.bind(`${host}:${Server_Add}`, grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
server.start();
console.log("Chat Server started on", Server_Add);

function callService() {
  var client = new grpcChat.ChatService(
    `${host}:${Client_Add}`,
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
  );
  const readline = require("readline");
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });

  var user = process.env.USER;
  var metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
  metadata.add("username", user);
  var call = client.chat(metadata);

  call.on("data", function (ChatMessage) {
    console.log(`${ChatMessage.from} ==> ${ChatMessage.message}`);
  });
  call.on("end", function () {
    console.log("Server ended call");
  });
  call.on("error", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  });

  rl.on("line", function (line) {
    if (line === "quit") {
      call.end();
      rl.close();
    } else {
      call.write({
        message: line,
      });
    }
  });

  console.log("Enter your messages below:");
}

setTimeout(callService, 7000);
```

Dockerfile

```docker
FROM node:14
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000 8000
CMD ["node", "server"]
```

docker-compose.yml file

```yml
version: '2.2'
services:
  Allen:
    image: grpc
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - proxynet
    depends_on:
      Bob:
        condition: service_healthy 
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
  Bob:
    image: grpc
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - proxynet
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
networks:
  proxynet:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to make a few changes to get your project to work, I'll explain them as I go.

In `server.js` I hardcoded the address the server binds to be `0.0.0.0` so the server will listen on all addresses.

I also made the address the client connects to configurable via a `HOST` environment variable.

#### `server.js`

```js
// Set client host from environment variable.
var host = process.env.HOST;
var server = new grpc.Server();
server.addService(grpcChat.ChatService.service, {
  chat: chat,
});

// Hardcoded server address
server.bind(`0.0.0.0:${Server_Add}`, grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
server.start();
console.log("Chat Server started on", Server_Add);

function callService() {
  var client = new grpcChat.ChatService(
    `${host}:${Client_Add}`,
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
  );
```

I had to do this because you're using a bridge network in your `docker-compose.yml` therefore they're no longer sharing the same network address as they would if you were running them on your host or using the `host` network type made available by Docker.

Because the server's effectively have their own IP addresses there is no need to use different ports such as `5000` and `8000` instead you can have them both run on the same port I've used `9090` as this is the typical port gRPC server's listen on.

However, the `9090` ports of the containers have been published on the host as `5000` and `8000` ports respectively in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

I have also installed `netcat` as a dependency in your `Dockerfile` so I could implement the healthcheck correctly in the `docker-compose.yml` by checking the server ports were accessible on `localhost` and `9090` internally relative to the container.

#### `Dockerfile`

```sh
FROM node:14
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
netcat \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 9090
CMD ["node", "server"]
```

I have added comments here to explain the other changes.

#### `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '2.2'
services:
  # Hostname of the container on bridge network
  allen:
    image: grpc
    environment:
      USER: Allen
      # Server port to bind to
      ADD_PORT: 9090
      # Client port
      FRND_PORT: 9090
      # Client hostname
      HOST: bob
    ports:
      - "8000:9090"
    networks:
      - proxynet
    depends_on:
      bob:
        condition: service_healthy 
    healthcheck:
      # Check server is listening on expected address/port
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "-zv", "localhost", "9090"]
      # The default is 30s which takes ages to detect health status
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    # Required in order to attach to the container and write messages
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  # Hostname of the container on bridge network
  bob:
    image: grpc
    environment:
      USER: Bob
      # Server port to bind to
      ADD_PORT: 9090
      # Client port
      FRND_PORT: 9090
      # Client hostname
      HOST: allen
    ports:
      - "5000:9090"
    networks:
      - proxynet 
    healthcheck:
      # Check server is listening on expected address/port
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "-zv", "localhost", "9090"]
      # The default is 30s which takes ages to detect health status
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    # Required in order to attach to the container and write messages
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
networks:
  proxynet:
    driver: bridge
```

I also guessed the definition of your gRPC service defined in `allenchat.proto`, probably not exactly correct but good enough to test.

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package io.mark.grpc.grpcChat;

message ChatMessage {
  string message = 1;
  string from = 2;
  string fromName = 3;
}

service ChatService {
  rpc chat(stream ChatMessage) returns (stream ChatMessage);
}
```

Once I had both containers started I ran `docker attach <CONTAINER>` to attach my shell to the respective containers in order to send messages to confirm both containers were connected and could send messages back and fourth.

#### Terminal log

```sh
[+] Running 2/1
 ⠿ Container shubhi-bob-1    Recreated                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 ⠿ Container shubhi-allen-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
Attaching to shubhi-allen-1, shubhi-bob-1
shubhi-bob-1    | Chat Server started on 9090
shubhi-allen-1  | Chat Server started on 9090
shubhi-bob-1    | Enter your messages below:
shubhi-allen-1  | Enter your messages below:
> Test
> Allen ==> Test
shubhi-bob-1    | Test
shubhi-allen-1  | Bob ==> Test
```